# Does the "rule of the last antecedent" apply to casual conversation?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers

The Supreme Court recently decided [Lockhart v United States](http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/15pdf/14-8358_o7jp.pdf) using the rule that

> a limiting clause or phrase . . . should ordinarily
>   be read as modifying only the noun or phrase that it
>   immediately follows.

to interpret

> ... the laws
>   of any State relating to aggravated sexual abuse, sexual
>   abuse, or abusive sexual conduct involving a minor
>   or ward, ...

so that "involving a minor or ward" only modifies "abusive sexual conduct", and not "aggravated sexual abuse" or "sexual abuse".

Is that a rule that should be followed in casual conversation? For example how would you understand,

- > Is there any beer or soda in the fridge?
- > I bought a shirt and shoes that fit.
- > I don't like to talk to strangers or people I live with.

Also, are there some rules of cadence or intonation that might help to distinguish the meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those "rules" that exists only in old-fashioned grammar books. In the real world, which antecedent is being modified is decided by the much more practical principle of what makes the most sense.

There is an interesting test for machine intelligence, the Winograd Schema Challenge, based on precisely this principle as it requires the intelligence to draw on encycopedic knowledge to extract meaning from a sentence. Lets borrow a couple of sentences used in this test.

*The city councilmen refused the demonstrators a permit because they advocated violence.*

*The city councilmen refused the demonstrators a permit because they feared violence.*

In the first sentence, it makes sense that the 'they' is the last antecedent, because demonstrators advocating violence is a good reason to refuse them a permit.

In the second sentence, demonstrators fearing violence is not a good reason to refuse them a permit, but the councilmen fearing violence is, so in this case the "last antecedent rule" doesn't work, and 'they' should be the councilmen.

But... The judge may have got it right even if it is for the wrong reasons. Bearing in mind that I am not a lawyer, looking at that thelist there doesn't seem to be much difference between "sexual abuse" and "abusive sexual conduct", unless the latter is specific to "involving a minor or ward", in which case the 'minor or ward' would indeed modify only "abusive sexual conduct".

A quick Google search does throw up "abusive sexual conduct" as a a crime specific to child victims, [here](http://www.azleg.state.az.us/legtext/43leg/2r/bills/hb2657p.htm) and [here].[2](http://www.jamesahernandez.com/Military-Law/Sexual-Offense-Definitions-of-U-C-M-J.shtml)

Comment: Wow, that's a great example.